Pvlib. The production timeline does not correspond to the weather file timeline
I´m converting some weather data into pv production, the weather file has solar radiation from 5am till 7:45PM, so it is a standard solar profile for this region. The problem is that when I use that weather file with mc.run_model(weather) the resulting profile only has energy production from 6:45am to 4PM which doesn´t make much sense.
I tried to change many variables such as surface tilt and surface azimuth but as expected it only changed the amount of energy produced, I tracked all of the sets of data and the source of the problem is definitely the ModelChain and the mc.run_model(weather) but i don´t know what else I should change.
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pvlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pvlib.pvsystem import PVSystem, FixedMount
from pvlib.location import Location
from pvlib.modelchain import ModelChain
from pvlib.temperature import TEMPERATURE_MODEL_PARAMETERS
from pvlib.iotools import read_tmy3
from pvlib.solarposition import get_solarposition
from pvlib import irradiance

temperature_model_parameters = TEMPERATURE_MODEL_PARAMETERS['sapm']['open_rack_glass_glass']
latitude=-40.38
longitude=8.39

dados=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/henri/OneDrive - Universidade de Lisboa/tese/scripts/weather_aveiro_final.csv')
sandia_modules = pvlib.pvsystem.retrieve_sam('SandiaMod')
cec_inverters = pvlib.pvsystem.retrieve_sam('cecinverter')
sandia_module = sandia_modules['Canadian_Solar_CS5P_220M___2009_']
cec_inverter = cec_inverters['ABB__MICRO_0_25_I_OUTD_US_208__208V_']
location=Location(latitude, longitude)

system=PVSystem(surface_tilt=-latitude, 
                surface_azimuth=400,
                module_parameters=sandia_module,inverter_parameters=cec_inverter,
                temperature_model_parameters=temperature_model_parameters)
mc = ModelChain(system, location)
weather = pd.DataFrame()
weather['Time']=pd.to_datetime(dados['Time'])
weather.set_index('Time',inplace=True)
weather['temp_air'] = dados['Avg_Temp'].values
weather['ghi'] = dados['GHI (W/m2)'].values

# Calculates solar position 
weather = weather.resample('15min').interpolate()
solar_position = location.get_solarposition(weather.index)
#Calculates Irradiance components (DNI e DHI) from GHI
dni = pvlib.irradiance.disc( weather['ghi'], solar_position['apparent_zenith'], weather.index)
weather['dni'] = dni['dni']
weather['dhi'] = weather['ghi'] - dni['dni'] * np.cos(np.radians(solar_position['apparent_zenith']))
#VERIFICAR INDEX!!!!

# Calculates efective irradiance
total_irrad = pvlib.irradiance.get_total_irradiance(
    surface_tilt=-latitude,
    surface_azimuth=400,
    dni=weather['dni'],
    ghi=weather['ghi'],
    dhi=weather['dhi'],
    solar_zenith=solar_position['apparent_zenith'],
    solar_azimuth=solar_position['azimuth'])

weather['poa_global'] = total_irrad['poa_global']

weather.to_csv('teste_radicao.csv')
# # Runs ModelChain
mc.run_model(weather=weather)
ac_power=mc.results.dc
ac_power['P [W/m2]']=ac_power['p_mp'].values
ac_power['E [kWh/m2]']=ac_power['P [W/m2]']*0.25*10**(-3)
ac_power.to_csv('producao_pv.csv')
plt.figure()
plt.plot(ac_power['p_mp'])

